# Increasing download speed by using multiple IP addresses? - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, http, file-download, wget

quite often sites **limit download speed** per ip address or identified user.

Is it possible to use a tool such as **wget** in order to overcome this limitation?

---

Ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wget, the option you are looking for is `--bind-address=`.

Note that

1. You need to have a machine with multiple interfaces,
2. You can only speed up with multiple concurrent downloads, and
3. If there are per-IP restrictions that are intended to be per-user / per-customer restrictions, then by evading them you are in the wrong, even if you are not breaking the law or an agreement.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is possible to bypass limitations in the server by opening multiple connections.

But these restrictions were probably put there for a reason and by deliberately avoiding them you might be breaking the terms of service for the site. Do this with caution.

Comment: I think opening multiple connections would be the solution in my case, but not sure wget provides this :S

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the "axel" package to speed up downloads - it does not use multiple IP's or multiple users, but will open multiple simultaneous download streams.

The real question is if you're experiencing slow downloads because of a deliberate configuration/policy choice, or because of a failure to optimize the delivery system(s) for maximum speed.

If it's the former, you probably won't be successful in evading the restrictions over the long term. If it's the latter, sometimes you can make up for the site admins' shortcomings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can ssh to as many compurers as you want/can and download more files at the same time.

I tried to download the same file from one site one times, but later I found they dont support continuing unfinished downloads - hence downloading only other part of file than the beginning.

Comment: This is likely meant to be a comment, however, you don't yet have 50 reputation to make comments.  It will happen soon enough though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sites limiting the download speed or number of parallel connections per user is understandable (service providing tactics of companies, free ; individual ; enterprise services). But limiting the download per IP address is harsh since a large group of IP addresses are masked under one ISP's public IP. Well coming to the question...

1) If the speed is limited per user you can't do much as any request you rise in the name of that user can be easily tracked by server limiting the download speed.

2) But if the speed is limited per IP address (I am not sure how practical it is), and if you have multiple interfaces in the system which have different public IP's, then you can use programs like `curl` or `wget` to bind to specific interface and request a particular range of the file with HTTP header `Range: bytes=start-end`. But how messy it would be! You need to determine the file length and manually you need to dissect the file among multiple interfaces and connections. And finally you need to append them together. Not to mention pausing and resuming download also gives you hard time.

## Any projects in that direction ?

I started working on a project whose use case is same as you asked. Its completely written in C. Here is a link to my project, Multiple Interface Downloader (MID) https://github.com/m0hithreddy/MID .

- MID uses SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option to bind to a specific interface, so in most of the cases you require super user permissions and CAP_NET_RAW capability (root user has).
- MID determines the network interfaces to use in the download and adopts two step split for downloading the content.

  - First step: The file is divided among network interfaces (in real time).
  - Second step: Further the file is divided among several **HTTP range requests** that arise from that particular interface (**NOTE**: Server should support them at the first place to make all of this possible)

MID supports HTTP and HTTPS protocol.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

a) you could use GhostBrowser, it can use a different IP address by tab, but the free version has the limit to 4 identities;

b) configure squid proxy to use a list of random defined IP address